# Form startPosition won't change - C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I have an application called ApplicationSettings, that is a windows form, and if you press the START button, it should open another form, called Visualizer.
I have designed ApplicationSettings with the visual studio designer, but I didn't touch Visualizer with the designer.
I want to change the start position of Visualizer. However, I tried about 30 different ways, and I still can't get it to move.
When I run the program, this is how it starts:
[image]

You can see behind Visualizer, that ApplicationSettings StartPosition is set to CenterScreen (with the designer).
The problem that I encounter is that I CANT CHANGE Visualizer's StartPosition!
I tried changing it through designer. Changed StartPostion to several different options - CenterParent, CenterScreen, Manual, but it keeps staying this way.
I've tried changing it before InitializeComponents, after InitializeComponents, nothing helps!

```
public Visualizer(AlgorithmTypes.eAlgorithmType i_AlgorithmType, int i_BoardHeight, int i_BoardWidth)
        {
            m_BoardHeight = i_BoardHeight;
            m_BoardWidth = i_BoardWidth;
            m_algorithmType = i_AlgorithmType;
            if(m_BoardHeight > 40 || m_BoardWidth > 40)
            {
                m_ButtonSize = new Size(15, 15);
            }
            else if(m_BoardHeight > 30 || m_BoardWidth > 30)
            {
                m_ButtonSize = new Size(18, 18);
            }
            
            InitializeComponent();
            this.TopMost = true;
            
        }
```

I simply want Visualizer to start at the center of the screen. What am I missing here? Why doesn't it change its start position?

Codes for initialize components:
Visualizer:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // Visualizer
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(9F, 20F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Center;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
            this.Name = "Visualizer";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.Manual;
            this.Text = "Visualizer";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.VisualizerForm_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
```

ApplicationSettings:

```
// Lots of buttons and labels being created
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(9F, 20F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(504, 461);
            this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.StartButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.WidthTextBox);
            this.Controls.Add(this.HeightTextBox);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.KeyPreview = true;
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.Name = "ApplicationSettings";
            this.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "Searching Algorithms Visualiser";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.ApplicationSettings_Load);
            this.groupBox1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.groupBox2.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();
```

How I call the Visualizer:

```
private void StartButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if((DFSButton.Checked || BFSButton.Checked || AStarButton.Checked)
               && (FirstSizeButton.Checked || SecondSizeButton.Checked || CustomRadioButton.Checked))
            {
                AlgorithmTypes.eAlgorithmType algoType = getAlgorithmType();
                getHeightAndWidth(out int height, out int width);
                if(algoType != AlgorithmTypes.eAlgorithmType.NoChoice)
                {
                    Visualizer startVisualizer = new Visualizer(algoType, height, width);
                    startVisualizer.ShowDialog(this);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It may help if you show the code in InitializeComponent concerning the forms own settings and show the code how you create/show the visualizer form.

Comment: Don't see anything obvious. Setting the location between the call to the constructor and ShowDialog in your StartButton_Clicked event has no effect?

Comment: @Ralf No effect at all :-( Perhaps Visual Studio bug? Or is it something with the ApplicationSettings I need to change? Because changing ApplicationSettings works well. I changed Application Settings StartPosition to be Manual, but Visualizer stays at the same position!! Can't believe I'm stuck on this.

Comment: Keep the `InitializeComponent();` method in the default ctor and you should call the default ctor from the parameters ctor. `public Visualizer(..., ...) : this() { ... }`. Use the designer to set the Form's properties. `StartPostion`, `TopMost`, ...etc. Also, you really need to replace the matrix controls (PicuteBoxes?) with a simple filling and/or drawing rectangles routine. Having that much of controls in a Form is not a good design.

Comment: @dr.null Thank you. I tried your solution, but the windows stays at the same place as before. It doesn't want to move.   About the matrix controls: I'm using cs files, not xml or xaml. So I don't have rectangles or other useful features to build a better matrix.

Comment: In the `Visualizer` Form, you should set `StartPosition = StartPosition.CenterScreen;` not `StartPosition.Manual` and it should show up at the center of the screen unless you are doing something that moves the Form. Like moving the Form by mistake instead of a child control. Double check your code. As for the drawing part, you can draw almost anything in WinForms, google and you'll find an endless list of examples.